# jQuery document ready and keypress to call one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have this as a document ready function that triggers when the enter key is pressed, but I keep getting the error message "enableEnter is undefined".

```
    $(document).ready(enableEnter());

    $('#formPartOverride').keypress(function enableEnter(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ezpConsole.partOverride.retrieveParts();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't see the `enableEnter` function being declared anywhere in your code.

Comment: @MelanciaUK look inside of `keypress()`

Comment: that is because your `enableEnter` function is not visible to the `.ready` call, it is being used like an anonymous function so its not visible to anything else

Comment: You clearly misunderstood the way a `callback function` works with `event handling` in `jQuery`.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought this website was for asking questions about things you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the correct way of achieving this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // When the DOM is ready, attach the event handler.
    $('#formPartOverride').keypress(function (event) {            
        enableEnter(event);
    });
});

// enableEnter is accessible in the whole page scope.
function enableEnter(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ezpConsole.partOverride.retrieveParts();
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FS967/)

Answer (score 0):

Create the function `enableEnter()` outside of the `keypress1 function - it is only defined in the scope of the`keypress`function, so will not be available to anything above that specific scope. You could encase the entire script inside the`$(document).ready()` function such as:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#formPartOverride').keypress(function enableEnter(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ezpConsole.partOverride.retrieveParts();
        }
    });

});
```

This will wait until the document ready to make the enclosed script available.